# Mongodb too high I/O

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb instance and it shows too high iops (approx 100%).

There is 100 Gb space volume in which 50 GB is free but its shows approx 100% iops in iotop output please see the below output:

```
Total DISK READ :24G28.09 M/s | Total DISK WRITE :60G32.25 K/s
Actual DISK READ:24G34.01 M/s | Actual DISK WRITE:61G0.00 B/s
 TID  PRIO USER       DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN  IO     COMMAND
 3210 be/4 mongodb    13.35 M/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 99.99 % mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
16943 be/4 mongodb    14.68 M/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 99.99 % mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
 8217 be/4 mongodb    64.50 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 73.83 % mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
 2331 be/4 mongodb     0.00 B/s   32.25 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. Whats the issue I am so worry about my issue?

Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: do you use the batch operation?

Comment: try to inspect what operations are running now and how much time does they spend using `db.currentOp()`

Comment: and stay calm while fixing DB, cos opposite state makes snowball grow